# javascript set interval time every 3 sec for first 6 seconds, then 5 seconds continuously till i receive the answer

Tags: javascript

I want to ping a server for response every 3 seconds for the first 6 seconds, after that I want to increase the interval time to 5 seconds till i get the response. I did the first part, I'm trying to solve the next 5 seconds ping

```
var firstPing = 3000,
    pingStop = 6000,
    pingForever = 5000;
var ping = setInterval(function() { execute() }, firstPing);

setTimeout(function() {clearInterval(ping)}, pingStop);

setInterval(function() {execute()}, pingForever);

function execute() {
    console.log('hello: ' + new Date().getSeconds());
  // After successful response, clearInterval();

}
```

Comment: `setInterval(execute, firstPing)` is shorter. You don't need all those anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that manages the transition of the ping from 3 to 5 secs.

```js
const firstPing = 3000,
      pingStop = 6000,
      pingForever = 5000;
let currentPing = 0;

let ping = setInterval(function() { execute() }, firstPing);

function execute() {
    console.log('hello: ' + new Date().getSeconds());
    // After successful response, clearInterval();
    if(++currentPing >= 2 ) {
        clearInterval(ping);
        ping = setInterval(() => execute(), pingForever);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Might it be simpler to just call execute() every 1 second and only have execute do something when an incrementing counter variable is a certain value?

```
var ping = setInterval(function() { execute() }, 1000);

let v = 0;
function execute() {
  v++;
  if(v==3 || v==6 || (v>6 && v%5 == 1))
    console.log('hello: ' + new Date().getSeconds());
  // After successful response, clearInterval();
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use count variable, you have `firstPing` of `3sec`. Instead of clearing the interval you can update the firstPing with `pingForever`.

```js
var firstPing = 3000,
    pingStop = 6000,
    pingForever = 5000;

let count = 0;

var ping = setInterval(() => {
    execute();
    firstPing = (count === 2) ? pingForever : firstPing;
    count++;
    console.log(count, firstPing);
}, firstPing);

function execute() {
    // console.log('hello: ' + new Date().getSeconds());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `setTimeout` for simplicity.

```
var found = null;

function tryRequest() {
  if (found) return;

  // send request
  // in successful response, set 'found' to 'true'

  setTimeout(tryRequest, found == null ? 3000 : 5000);
  found = false;
}

setTimeout(tryRequest, 3000);
```